# Accessing text in tkinter button for storage as variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm attempting to create a 2D game with tkinter (very simple) and I have a small problem with my buttons.

I used the following code to create a 'toggle' button which changed from Up to Down and vice-versa when clicked:

```
def toggleud(icycle = it.cycle(['Down', 'Up'])):

    stateud = next(icycle)
    updowntoggle['text'] = str(stateud)

updowntoggle = tk.Button(scr, text = 'Up', command = toggleud)
updowntoggle.pack()
```

When implemented, it works very well! However, I then would like to access which state the button is on so it can be used to move the character in the grid, e.g. if the button said 'Up' then the character would move down and vice-versa. I tried 
`udtogglechoice = updowntoggle['text']`
but this didn't seem to work. Any advice?

Comment: "didn't seem to work" is not a problem description. Please provide your attempt and the complete error message, if you're getting one. Otherwise, describe the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#reference), you can create a `StringVar` variable and get its value. When the value of the variable changes, the button is updated.

```
from tkinter import StringVar
toggle_var = StringVar()
updowntoggle = tk.Button(scr, text = 'Up', textvariable=toggle_var, command = toggleud)

#to get the value
def toggleud():
#your code here
    print(toggle_var.get())
```